# configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first

Tags: makefile, build

I was trying to install [this library](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1) on my mac. I first entered `./autogen.sh` and it outputs

```
lindys-MacBook-Pro:secp256k1-master satya$ ./autogen.sh 
glibtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, 'build-aux'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/ltmain.sh'
glibtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'build-aux/m4'.
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/libtool.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltoptions.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltsugar.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/ltversion.m4'
glibtoolize: copying file 'build-aux/m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.ac:10: installing 'build-aux/compile'
configure.ac:9: installing 'build-aux/missing'
Makefile.am: installing 'build-aux/depcomp'
```

I then ran `make` and it shows the following error.

```
lindys-MacBook-Pro:secp256k1-master satya$ configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /Applications/SageMath/config/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
configure: error: source directory already configured; run "make distclean" there first
```

When entered `make distclean` it shows

```
lindys-MacBook-Pro:secp256k1-master satya$ sudo make distclean
Password:
make: *** No rule to make target `distclean'.  Stop.
lindys-MacBook-Pro:secp256k1-master satya$ sudo make clean
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue. I first deleted `build-aux` directory and then ran `./autogen.sh` and `./configure` commands again. If you face similar error in some other package, may be try deleting your build directory and type `./configure` again.